# Using threads to sort two halves of an array, but only second half is being sorted

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, sorting, pthreads

I wrote a quick program to sort two halves of one array, when i test the sort it works fine with one array, however when I split the array into two and pass a half to each thread for sorting, when they're done and I print the array, only the second half looks sorted. What am I doing wrong? Below are my sorting function and main.

```
void *sort(void *object){

  struct array_struct *structure;
  structure = (struct array_struct *) object;

  int *array = structure->partition;
  int size = structure->size;
  qsort(array, size, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

  printf("Sorted %d elements.\n", size);
}
```

and this is my main, assume all includes are fine, and compilation is fine also, this is not all of my code, just the parts pertaining to my problem.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){


int segments = 2;
pthread_t threads[segments];

int i, *numbers; //iterator i, and pointer to int array 'numbers'
numbers = randomArray(); //return an array of size 50 filled with random ints



for(i = 0; i < segments; i++){
    struct array_struct array;//struct to pass as argument on thread creation

        int *partition = numbers + (i * (50/segments));//obtain the first index of partition
        array.partition = partition; //when i = 0 partition is 0 through 24, when i = 1 partition is 25 through 49 
        array.size = 50/segments; //25
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sort, (void *) &array);

}

for(i = 0; i < segments; i++){
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}

for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
}

pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

and here is my output if it helps:

```
Sorted 25 elements.
Sorted 25 elements.
```

19
16
14
16
20
6
17
13
8
39
18
0
26
46
45
17
7
46
45
29
15
38
43
19
17
0
2
4
7
12
12
12
14
16
17
20
22
22
23
26
29
30
32
33
37
38
38
43
43
46

Comment: `array` is local to each iteration of your loop. As written, this is undefined behavior. In this case, what is happening is that the compiler is reusing the storage on each iteration. Print out `&array[0]` inside each thread to see this directly.

Comment: So you have behaviour you cannot explain.  And yet you give us code that may or may not reproduce the problem, based off your own ability to eliminate what you think is not important?  If you knew what caused the problem **you would not be posting here** with this question.  Produce minimal code in 1 file that actually compiles and actually reproduces the problem.  After making it minimal, test the actual code to see it reproduces the problem.  Then format it in your editor with 4 leading spaces.  Test again.  Can you make it shoeter?  No?  Then copy paste.

Comment: In case you missed @Yakk's explanation, here is [how to create a minimal, compilable, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Yakk yes, i have behavior i cannot explain but i have tested extensively before passing on to threads, so i know WHERE the problem lies. Apparently someone was able to identify the issue already. Thanks for being helpful though.

Comment: @Nemo ah yes i see what you mean now that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an argument to your first thread, `array`, and then immediately overwriting the contents of that struct with the arguments to the second thread.  Both threads will therefore see the arguments for the second thread.

What you should do is have two separate arguments.  For example make `array` an array of 2 structs and pass `&array[0]` to the first thread and `&array[1]` to the second thread.

Also, it is dangerous to declare `array` in the scope of the for loop.  Once the for loop ends, that variable is out of scope and your threads may read into a dead variable.  You should declare `array` at the function level so that it remains alive for the threads to access it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I see exactly how that would cause a problem now. And thanks for the tips, i'll definitely keep them in mind and implement them!